# Vue - multiple parents use the same child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is there a way in Vue.js for multiple parents to use the same child ?

I would like multiple delete buttons to fire a single modal with different contents.

**Example**

myfile.html:

```
<table id="app" class="table table-striped table-sm table-responsive-md">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="post">
            <td>Test2</td>
            <td>
                <delete-confirm popup-title="Are you sure ?" popup-message="Message 1">
                    Delete
                </delete-confirm>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="post">
            <td>Test article</td>
            <td>
                <delete-confirm popup-title="Are you sure ?" popup-message="Message 2">
                    Delete
                </delete-confirm>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('delete-confirm', require('./components/DeleteConfirm.vue'));
Vue.component('magnific-popup', require('./components/MagnificPopup.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

components/DeleteConfirm.vue:

```
<template>
    <span>
        <button ref="button" @click="showConfirmation($event.target)" class="btn btn-danger">
            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> <slot></slot>
        </button>

        <magnific-popup v-on:click="click" ref="popup">
            <h2 slot="title">{{ popupTitle }}</h2>
            <p slot="content">{{ popupMessage }}</p>
        </magnific-popup>
    </span>
</template>

<script>
    import $ from 'jquery';

    export default {
        props: ['popupTitle', 'popupMessage'],
        methods: {
            showConfirmation(target) {
                this.$refs.popup.open(target);
            },
            click(type) {
                this.$refs.popup.close();

                if (type === 'confirm') {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '404me',
                        type: 'DELETE',
                    }).then(() => { /* TODO */ }).catch(() => { /* TODO */ });
                }
            }
        },
    };
</script>
```

components/MagnificPopup.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="white-popup zoom-anim-dialog mfp-hide">
        <div class="container bg-light col-8 mx-auto p-3 rounded">
            <slot name="title"></slot>
            <div class="popup-content">
                <slot name="content"></slot>
            </div>
            <div class="popup-actions">
                <button type="button" @click="sendYes" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Yes
                </button>
                <button type="button" @click="sendNo" class="btn btn-secondary">
                    No
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import $ from 'jquery';
    require('magnific-popup');

    export default {
        methods: {
            sendYes() {
                this.$emit('click', 'confirm');
            },
            sendNo() {
                this.$emit('click', 'cancel');
            },
            close: function() {
                $.magnificPopup.close();
            },
            open: function(trigger) {
                $.magnificPopup.open({
                    items: {
                        src: this.$el,
                    },
                    midClick: true,
                    mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in',
                    fixedContentPos: false,
                    fixedBgPos: true,
                    overflowY: 'auto',
                    closeBtnInside: true,
                    preloader: false,
                    removalDelay: 300,
                });
            },
        }
    };
</script>

<style lang="scss">
    @import '~magnific-popup/src/css/main';
    @import '../../css/magnific-popup.css';
</style>
```

It works well but the downside is that it creates one magnific-popup *dom element* per button component.

[Generated html code (describes the problem better)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWztl.png) - I'm not allowed to embed pictures.

---

I would prefer to avoid having to declare a `<magnific-popup>` in each file that uses the `<button-delete>` component (e.g. in *myfile.html*).

Is there any way to add this popup component as a dependency that is only added once to the DOM and re-used later ?

---

**What I want to achieve would be something like**

Only `<delete-confirm>` elements declared in *myfile.html*, no `<magnific-popup>`.

Declare `MagnificPopup` as a dependency of `DeleteConfirm` so that whenever one or more `<delete-confirm>` element is used, a single `<magnific-popup>` element is added to the DOM of *myfile.html*.

Comment: I just came across [vue-magnific](https://gist.github.com/antixrist/11f7d78fe680eb3bc15203a940b6b4f8). Could it be of any help?

Answer (score 0):

Put the popup in the parent (at the same level the `button-delete`s are used). On click, each button should [`$emit` an event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit) that the parent handles by doing whatever you want done to the popup.

Comment: The parent is my "app" and I want to avoid having to declare one <magnific-popup> each time I declare a <delete-confirm> in my "app".
I wasn't clear on what I was trying to achieve, I edited my question to explain myself better.

Comment: I was going to say it's not possible, but I think it's just awkward. You need to have a module that creates and exports an instance (using `new`) and import that module/instance into your `delete-confirm`, then `$mount` it at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

Register your `<magnific-popup>` globally in your `main.js` (or wherever you create your root Vue instance). This way the component is only registered once but it will be availible to all child components.

You haven't provided a [working sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question but in my local tests, this is generating only one modal/popup - not several on top of each others.

```js
// main.js

// Register your popup...
import MagnificPopup from '@/components/MagnificPopup'
Vue.component('magnific-popup', MagnificPopup)

// ...just before you create your Vue instance
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  //...
})
```

Comment: I did that already. I didn't explain myself well and edited my question to provide a working example and better explanation on what I was trying to achieve.